# Selecting columns by index number

Tags: excel, vba

I want to detect and highlight changes in a given Table A by comparing it with some other Table B.

I get

> error number 1004: range_global failed.

Here is a part of  my attempt:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub changeFinder()
    ...
    For j = 1 To m
        sht.Columns(j + 1).Insert
        sht.Columns(j + 1).Insert
        For i = 2 To n
            sht.Cells(i, j + 1).Value = Application.VLookup(sht.Cells(i, j), sht2.Range("Columns(1):Columns(j)"), j, False)
        Next i
        ...    
    Next j

End Sub
```

My goal is for Table A: To loop over every column j. And for every column j I want to create two temporary columns j+1 and j+2 to the right.
I want to fill j+1 with VLookup over the columns 1 to j from Table B.
The latter seems to fail.

Is there a "natural" way to select the Columns 1 to j+1 from a specific sheet, when I don't know the alphabetical name of these columns, but only the index numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using `Application.VLookup`

- Replace

  ```
  sht.Cells(i, j + 1).Value = Application.VLookup(sht.Cells(i, j), sht2.Range("Columns(1):Columns(j)"), j, False)`
  ```

  with:

  ```
  sht.Cells(i, j + 1).Value = Application.VLookup( _
      sht.Cells(i, j), sht2.Columns(1).Resize(, j), j, False)
  ```
- But I think you would be better off by using `Application.Match`.
- Also, note that a backward loop will be necessary for this to work correctly:

  ```
  For j = m To 1 Step -1
  ```

  You don't want to lookup in the inserted columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked out just fine.

Now I have a whole lot of other things to fix, but at least the for-loop goes over every column. :D

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `Range.EntireColumn`, as it's easier to introduce index numbers to the `.Range` property.
So the line within the second `For` loop becomes:

```
sht.Cells(i, j + 1).Value = Application.VLookup(sht.Cells(i, j), sht2.Range("A1:A" & j).EntireColumn, j, False)
```